# jQuery to function, grabbing a SPANS value

Tags: jquery, html

First post here, but have been using Stack for trying to learn some jQuery.
I am currently trying to reuse a bit of code and can use some help.

I have some data that is outputted in this type of format, and I am having a hard time understanding how to grab the text that ends up in the "columnValue" span for each DIV that starts with "itm_prodesc"
Here is a sample of the html -

```
<div class="GridDetails" id="itm_proddesc167">
  <span id="columnName">Description</span>
  : 
  <span id="columnValue">data data data data data data data data</span>
</div>
<div class="GridDetails" id="itm_proddesc168">
  <span id="columnName">Description</span>
  : 
  <span id="columnValue">data data data data data data data data</span>
</div>
```

And this is the jQuery function I am using re-using to try and grab the text of the columnValue spans -

```
  function prodListing(){
    $("div[name^='itm_proddesc']").find(".columnValue")

    $(".columnValue").each(function(){
        var $columnValueGrab = $(this).text();
        var $ProdDesc = $columnValueGrab.split(';');
        var $ul = $("<div class=ProdDesc></div>");

        for(i=0;i < $ProdDesc.length; i++){

             if($ProdDesc[i] !== undefined && $ProdDesc[i] !== '')

             {
                 if(i==0){
                     $ul.append("<h3 class='ProdTitle'>"+$ProdDesc[i] +"</h3>");
                 }
                 else{
                     $ul.append("<li class='ProdDesc'>"+$ProdDesc[i] +"</li>");
                 }

             }
        }

        $(this).html(" ");
        $(this).append($ul);

    });
}
```

Yes...the "rougue" colons are actually part of the HTML output as well...
Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: in html it is `ID` in js it is `class` which is which? ID should be unique in context

Comment: If your reffering to the ids are unique

Comment: `span id="columnValue"` i see this is not unique

Comment: You're calling `.find()` but not doing anything with it. What's the point of that?

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that I had not copy the full JQuery into the original post. I have added the rest of the code with the first suggestion make.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.each()` on the result of `.find()`. And the first selector should be `id^=`, not `name^=`.

You also need to fix the HTML to use `class` rather than `id` for the repeated elements.

```js
$("div[id^='itm_proddesc']").find(".columnValue").each(function() {
  var $columnValueGrab = $(this).text();
  console.log($columnValueGrab);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="GridDetails" id="itm_proddesc167">
  <span class="columnName">Description</span> :
  <span class="columnValue">data data data data data data data data</span>
</div>
<div class="GridDetails" id="itm_proddesc168">
  <span class="columnName">Description</span> :
  <span class="columnValue">data data data data data data data data</span>
</div>
```

Comment: sir in html markup `columnValue` is an id i think OP should clarify it

Comment: First off, "Thank you" for taking a moment to help me, I appreciate it greatly...

Comment: First off, "Thank you" for taking a moment to help me, I do not have any control of the HTML output of this data or the structure of it.
I am only trying to correct its viewing in a web browser using a snip of JQuery that was readily available and currently doin the same "job" on a different set of HTML data.

Comment: Sorry, but duplicate IDs are simply invalid HTML. jQuery won't find them.

Comment: Thank you again....any ides on how I can parse the data in "ColumnValue" into a bulled list working with just what I have?

Comment: Use `split()` to turn it into an array, then use a loop to add each array element as a list item.